# Pandas pivot table - ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

[image: Seaborn Heatmap]
I want to add columns (data for additional years) to my seaborn heatmap.
This is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December',
                             'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
                   'Year': [2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,
                            2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,],
                   'hPM2.5': [18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5,
                              18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5,
                              18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5,
                              18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5]})

cats = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
    'July','August','September','October','November','December']
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype('category', 
                              ordered=True,
                              categories=cats)

df2 = df.pivot("Month", "Year", "hPM2.5")
sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True)
```

So to try get 2012 data in, the pivot table seems to require 24 entries of Jan, Feb etc and of 2011, 2011...2012, 2012.. otherwise I get:
ValueError: arrays must all be same length. But as I repeat Jan, Feb. etc it gives this duplicate values error. I cannot seem to get the heatmap to work without using pivot table given by seaborn example. How can I get round this problem?

Comment: This has nothing to do with seaborn, your problem is that you're giving a list of len 48 for `hPM2.5` while Month and Years are only of len(24)

Comment: I reformatted the code portion of your data: each of 'Month', 'Year' and 'hPM2.5' have 12 elements per line.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the construction of your dataframe, you're passing a list of length `48` for `hPM2.5` and only `24` for both `Month` and `Year`.

This works fine:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December',
                             'January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
                   'Year': [2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,2011,
                            2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,2012,],
                   'hPM2.5': [18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5,
                              18,17,21,14,7,7,8,7,9,11,23,5]})

cats = ['January','February','March','April','May','June',
    'July','August','September','October','November','December']
df['Month'] = df['Month'].astype('category', 
                              ordered=True,
                              categories=cats)

df2 = df.pivot("Month", "Year", "hPM2.5")
sns.heatmap(df2, annot=True)
```

[image: Seaborn heatmap]

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, you don't want to have to repeat Jan-Dec for each year and duplicate the years for each month in your input data. If that's the case, all you really need to do is enter it in the representation that you get out of the `.pivot()` instead. After a little cleanup of your input data, `df2.to_dict(orient="list")` gives:

```
{2011: [18, 17, 21, 14, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 11, 23, 5],
 2012: [18, 17, 21, 14, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 11, 23, 5]}
```

You can then just do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({2011: [18, 17, 21, 14, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 11, 23, 5], 
                   2012: [18, 17, 21, 14, 7, 7, 8, 7, 9, 11, 23, 5]}, index=cats)
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True)
```